# Retornar o ultimo resultado (atualizado pela data) de cada atributo

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tenho um banco de dados com uma tabela chamada `config`. Nela tenho as colunas `atributo`, `valor` e `data`:

```
atributo              valor       data_atualizacao

juros_composto     |    5      |    2019-01-25
juros_fixo         |    6      |    2019-01-27
juros_fracionario  |    9      |    2019-01-28
juros_mediador     |    4      |    2019-01-30
juros_composto     |    12     |    2019-01-31
juros_fixo         |    14     |    2019-02-01
juros_fracionario  |    16     |    2019-02-02
juros_mediador     |    18     |    2019-02-03
```

Preciso que me retorne os últimos atributos junto com os valores agrupados pela data de atualização, então o resultado deve aparecer assim:

```
atributo                valor

juros_composto     |    12     |
juros_fixo         |    14     |
juros_fracionario  |    16     |
juros_mediador     |    18     |
```

Eu fiz um código assim:

```
SELECT valor MAX(data_atualizacao) FROM config GROUP BY atributo;
```

Ele me retorna os ATRIBUTOs sem repetir (certinho) porém a coluna 'VALOR' retorna com os dados errados.

Comment: No caso você quer os últimos valores cadastrados no sistema Banco ?

Comment: No caso preciso dos ultimos valores dos atributos(sem repetir) ordenados por data. Então por exemplo, tenho 4 tipos de atributos, preciso que me retorne o valor desses atributos porém apenas os mais recentes sem repetir.

Comment: Vou mandar uma resposta com o SQL vê se funciona,

Comment: Ok.Pode deixar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma que consigo pensar de você fazer isso é fazer um segundo `select` dentro do `where` para determinar qual é a ultima data.

```
SELECT 
    atributo, valor, data_atualizacao
FROM
    config
WHERE
    data_atualizacao = (SELECT 
            MAX(config_sub.data_atualizacao)
        FROM
            config AS config_sub
        WHERE
            config.atributo = config_sub.atributo);
```

Testa ai e ve se funciona conforme o que você precisa.